# Redshift Materialized View: error when creating with glue catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I try to create a materialized view via spektrum from an external table in the glue data catalog

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "dev"."public"."table_name" AS
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM "awsdatacatalog"."my_db"."table_name"
```

but I get the following error and have no idea where to start looking for a solution:

```
Trying to make internal datasharing request for auto mounted catalog. code: 4
```